# Can a sequential always block be triggered by a short pulse from a combi block

Tags: verilog, compiler-optimization, system-verilog, hdl

Could a sequential always block be triggered by a short lived pulse coming from a combi block ?

I have tried to trigger the always block, by assigning a value and set the value back to 0 in an attempt to trigger the sequential always block but to no avail, below is the pseudo code

```
always_comb begin
 ...some code...
pulse_trigger = 1;
load_var= driver_var // assigning some values
pulse_trigger = 0;
 ...some code...
end

always @(pulse_trigger)begin
 ...some code part 2...
end
```

I expect by assigning 1 to pulse_trigger the "always@(pulse_trigger)" block to get activated, but in my VCS simulation this does not seem to be the case.

Maybe this is because the pulse trigger is assigned 1 and unassigned 1 in the same combi block, which takes 0 simulation time, so pulse_trigger might not appear to have changed values. Or this method should've triggered "always@(pulse_trigger)" and executed "...some code part 2..", because I am looking at the wrong values ?

Comment: but should the `always@(pulse_trigger)` be activated though ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In verilog simulation only a single always block can be evaluated at a time. So, until your `always_comb` finishes, no other always block can be evaluated. Therefore, no `pulse_trigger` change will be detected by simulation (because all changes happen inside  a single always block.

You can do something like that by adding delays (assuming this is not a synthesizable code):

```
always @* begin
  pulse_trigger = 1;
  load_var= driver_var // assigning some values
  #1 // << this will stop execution of the block for 1 time unit and allow others.
  pulse_trigger = 0;
end
```

However, the above code is **not** synthesizable but it can be a part of a test bench. 
Also, it is not allowed within `always_comb`.

Comment: Adding a blocking delay in combinational block means you could miss changes to the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

The result is indeterminate. The SystemVerilog standard is written so that simulators are free to jump between independent processes at any point. But most wait for an event or time control to suspend the process before jumping to another one.

If you want to guarantee a trigger, use a non-blocking assignment in the second assignment to `pulse_trigger` or use a named event.

```
always @* begin
  pulse_trigger = 1;
  load_var= driver_var // assigning some values
  pulse_trigger <= 0; // adds a delta cycle or <= #1 delay without blocking the process
end
```

Even better is replacing the second `always @` block with a function declaration, then calling the function instead of triggering an event.

Comment: hi dave, could you expand a little bit on what you mean by "use a non-blocking assignment in the second assignment to pulse_trigger or use a named event". thanks

Comment: It will cause a reliable glitch in the same time tick in simulation only. This behavior cannot be synthesized though. And you could have hard time debugging it since glitches are not easily displayed by waiveform tools.